# Clean Lisp Readability

Tags: coding-style, functional-programming, lisp

I am still trying to increase my lisp reading speed. As such, my first inclination is to try and name everything (usually in let bindings) to make up for my slow comprehension. In examples online, there is always a mix of some things being bound, and others just being used in place.

Like this silly s-expression to parse (1 2 4 + 4) could be written with let bindings:

```
 (let [first-nums  (take (- (count args) 2) args)
       last-num (last args)
       fun (nth args (- (count args) 2))]
    (reduce fun (conj first-nums last-num))))
```

Or without:

```
  (reduce (nth args (- (count args) 2))
          (conj (take (- (count args) 2) args)
                (last args)))))
```

On the one hand, giving good domain names to "concepts" is something that I believe very much when working in the c-style languages, and even though the scope of let is very strictly defined, it still feels very anti-functional to be binding state.
**What is your criteria for when to use bindings?**

Comment: There's nothing anti-functional about using `let`.

Comment: It's not binding state, it's naming values.

Comment: I had almost exactly the same thought when I started FP. Rest easy knowing let is just sugar around a function application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Giving things names is fine. It helps making things self-documenting. There is nothing wrong with it. If things are too obvious one might want to get rid of it sometimes:

```
(let ((number1 12)
      (number2 30))
  (+ number1 number2))
```

Above does not add much to the expression `(+ 12 30)`. But if you want to document domain values, then instead of

```
(let ((number1 12)        ; border width
      (number2 30))       ; table width
  (+ number1 number2))
```

better write

```
(let ((table-width 30)
      (border-width 12))
   (+ table-width border-width))
```

One question which remains is this: when you have a data structure, you want to use parts of it in some way and you want to give these parts temporary names - how to do that?

In your example, `LET` introduces the names and you provide hand-written code to extract the values.

Slighty 'better' could be a more descriptive approach:

```
(match-let (*args1 function arg2)                  ; a pattern
      expression                                   ; a data structure
   (reduce function (append args1 (list arg2))))   ; a body
```

Something like the above would make sense if you have to deal with such patterns often in the code. It would make the code more declarative.

Comment: That is very helpful actually, do you know if there is anything like that greedy *args in clojure?

Comment: @Steve: don't know about Clojure, but Common Lisp should have it in its libraries. http://www.cliki.net/pattern%20matching